# SPARQL QUERY OWL FILE

Tags: unicode, sparql, normalization, unicode-normalization

Could I ask you about a SPARQL query on an Ontology. I have a family.owl file is the ontology build from protege 3.4 with data:

```
Lan haschild Tuấn, 
Tùng haschild Tuấn.
```

I use Java and CORESE API on site (http://www-sop.inria.fr/edelweiss/software/corese/v2_4_0/manual/index.php#coreseapi ) to query the family.owl above. With the following SPARQL query:

```
PREFIX fm:< http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Ontology1287989576.owl#>

SELECT ?child
WHERE 
{ 
  fm:Lan fm:haschild ?child 
}
```

The result is Tuáº¥n (true result must be Tuấn)

If I replace "where" clause as: `WHERE { fm:Tùng fm:haschild ?child }` then the result is empty (true result must be Tuấn)

I know the wrong result at string "Tùng" and "Tuấn". This string has character unicode ù, ấ

Can you have me using unicode character in CORESE API to query owl file with sparql.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to escape the URIs so instead of:

```
fm:Tùng --> fm:T%C3%B9ng
```

and

```
fm:Tuấn --> fm:Tu%E1%BA%A5n
```

If you create the data in this way you should not have problems. It's not very advisable to have accents in the URIS so people tend to encode/escape URIs for that reason, and most languages have libraries to encode URIs. For instance in Python is as easy as ...

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.quote("Tùng")
'T%C3%B9ng'
>>> urllib.quote("Tuấn")
'Tu%E1%BA%A5n'
```